# Image Zoom In and Out with Recycler View Android

Tags: android, image, scroll, android-recyclerview, zooming

I am trying to implement a Recycler View in which the first item covers at-least half of the screen. This item has an image set as a background.
The behavior that i want to achieve is: when user scrolls upward the recycler view, the image should zoom in, and when user scrolls it downward, the image should zoom out and should be in original dimension as soon as the first item is completely visible.

I have tried using setScale() property on imageView but it's not working as expected. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Keep the first item in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead of placing it in `RecyclerView` and wrap both the views in `CoordinatorLayout`.

Then in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` add parallax effect using attribute `collapseMode="parallax"`

Finally, bound the `RecyclerView` scroll behavior to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` using property `layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

Comment: In case if you can't move your first item out of recyclerView then you have to have to create a separate header viewholder for it. Then animate it based on the amount of part visible by measuring height of that layout. But, I will not recommend this approach as for this all the computation will be performed on main thread.